# AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'factorplot'

Tags: seaborn

When attempting to use the **`factorplot`** function from the Seaborn library, an AttributeError is raised, stating that the module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'factorplot'.

I tried to create a factor plot using Seaborn's **`factorplot`** function with specified variables for x-axis ('size') and y-axis ('tip') from the provided dataset 'var'. I expected the factor plot to be generated without any errors, displaying the relationship between the variables 'size' and 'tip'.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-ba5c83bf1a4b> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 sns.factorplot(x='size',y='tip',data=var)
      2 plt.show()

AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'factorplot'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`seaborn.factorplot` was renamed to `seaborn.catplot` in [seaborn 0.9](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew/v0.9.0.html#api-changes)  and has been marked as deprecated since then. It was definitely removed in seaborn 0.12 ([see release notes](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew/v0.12.0.html#other-updates)).

So you should use [`seaborn.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) instead:

```
sns.catplot(x='size', y='tip', data=var, kind="point")
```

You must specify the value of the `kind` argument since in `catplot` its default value is `"strip"` instead of `"point"`.